borrowing error during compile time vs runtime
I have this:
let mut a = 6; //1
let b = &a; //2
let c = &mut a; //3
println!("{b}") //4

About rust ownerhip and borrowing rules, I understand that during compilation itself error is flagged if there is more than one borrowing with one involving mutability.
In above code, at line 3 there is a mutable borrowing after immutable borrowing in line 2, so it is not allowed as per rust rules.
I have this code in several IDEs like vsc, rustrover etc. These IDEs flag any compilation error, like missing ';'.
But error at line 3 is detected when I run the program(cargo run), but not as compilation error.
Shouldn't it be a compilation error?

I configure my IDE to run cargo check or cargo clippy periodically or on save, so any compilation errors not detected by rust-analyzer are then detected and displayed.  However for larger projects this gets too costly and I disable it.

You can compile your program with cargo build and that very much throws an error. rust-analyzer and other tools do not always detect all compiler errors, especially the borrow checker is expensive to run and thus might not run on every little change you make to your code for performance reasons.

These IDEs flag any compilation error

is a misconception on your part.

Another misconception:  "is detected when I run the program(cargo run)" - cargo run also compiles.
